# System Environment Variables is wrong

Tags: environment-variables, operating-system, system

I accidentally typed this when I wanted to change my Python path in the cmdline:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Path\To\Python"
```

and it made my environment variable to one line.

[it turned into one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jIF6.png)

It should really be like this (?):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DxiJ.png)

I tried reverting back but can't because I haven't turned on system protection.